# How to define pickup capacity based on container's agent attribute?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am trying to model an evacuation process. I have 25 shuttles (with a capacity of 25 people) and 35 buses (with a capacity of 40 people), and I need to dynamically define the pickup capacity based on whether the container agent has its type attributes defined as a bus or as a shuttle.

help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it, assuming your agent type for shuttles is called `Shuttle`:
[image]